# Graph of a solution for the different parameters

Tags: plotting, graphics

I want to plot for Sol for the different values of s=0,1,2. can some one guide

```
    Subscript[A, o] = -(E^Subscript[m, 2] - E^Subscript[m, 1])^(-1)
Subscript[B, o] = 1/(E^Subscript[m, 2] - E^Subscript[m, 1])
Subscript[m, 1] = ((-s)*Pr + Sqrt[(s*Pr)^2 - 4*Pr*(\[Delta] - I*w)])/2
Subscript[m, 2] = ((-s)*Pr - Sqrt[(s*Pr)^2 - 4*Pr*(\[Delta] - I*w)])/2
sol = (Subscript[A, o]*E^(Subscript[m, 1]*y) + Subscript[B, o]*E^(Subscript[m, 2]*y))*E^(I*w*t)
w = Pi; Pr = 1; \[Delta] = 1; t = 0; s = 1; 
Plot[ReIm[sol], {y, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All]
Plot3D[ReIm[sol], {s, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: Have you tried `Plot`? Or `ListPlot`? Honestly, I don't get your question.

Comment: yes.....but i did not get graph

Comment: Well, you know that you can plot that only of all variables are replaced by numerical values, do you? Please, also show what you have tried; often simple syntax errors are the cause.

Comment: Plot[[.sol /. {y, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All ]]

Comment: Two problems: (i) `w` and `y` are not specified and (ii) you data contains nonreal numbers. Try something like `w = 1; y = 2; Plot[ReIm[sol], {s, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All]`.

Comment: i have taken value of w=pi and how can i specify value of y while i have mentioned the range of {y,0,1}

Comment: @ShahidRafiq in some places you have defined 'w' and you are inputting  `Pi`  for `Omega`.

Comment: yes dear thanks for correction ...but still not received any graph

Comment: Maybe `w = Pi; Plot3D[ReIm[sol], {s, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All]`? Please notive that it is `Pi`, not `pi.

Comment: can you plz share ur email address. i want to mail you the file.

Comment: Edit your question to include your code. Convert cells to `Raw InputForm` then copy and paste into your question. Select pasted code then use indent icon `{ }` to format as code.

Comment: @Bob Hanlon done

Comment: @BobHanlon i have edited the code as per ur directions,

Comment: can u plz guide now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

Subscript[A, o] = -(E^Subscript[m, 2] - E^Subscript[m, 1])^(-1);
Subscript[B, o] = 1/(E^Subscript[m, 2] - E^Subscript[m, 1]);
Subscript[m, 1] = ((-s)*Pr + Sqrt[(s*Pr)^2 - 4*Pr*(δ - I*w)])/2;
Subscript[m, 2] = ((-s)*Pr - Sqrt[(s*Pr)^2 - 4*Pr*(δ - I*w)])/2;
sol = (Subscript[A, o]*E^(Subscript[m, 1]*y) + 
     Subscript[B, o]*E^(Subscript[m, 2]*y))*E^(I*w*t);
w = Pi; Pr = 1; δ = 1; t = 0;

Plot[Evaluate@Table[ReIm[sol], {s, 0, 2}], {y, 0, 1},
 PlotLabels -> Flatten[Outer[StringForm["`2`: s=`1`", #1, #2] &,
    Range[0, 2], {Re, Im}]],
 Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}]
```

[image]

```
Plot3D[Evaluate@ReIm[sol], {s, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 1},
 AxesLabel -> Automatic,
 PlotLegends -> {Re, Im},
 BaseStyle -> {14, Bold}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thaks a lot dear Bob

Comment: i m reciving the following "Plot::optx: "\!\(\*
StyleBox[\"\\\"Unknown option \\\"\", \"MT\"]\)\!\(\* StyleBox[\"PlotLabels\", \"MT\"]\)\!\(\* StyleBox[\"\"\", \"MT\"]\) in "

Comment: `PlotLabels` was introduced in v10.4. If using an earlier version, change `PlotLabels` to `PlotLegends`

Comment: 'Plot::optx: "\!\(\*
StyleBox[\"\\\"Unknown option \\\"\", \"MT\"]\)\!\(\* StyleBox[\"PlotLabels\", \"MT\"]\)\!\(\* StyleBox[\"\"\", \"MT\"]\) '

Comment: i m using matematica 7.0 its still not working

Comment: `PlotLegends` was introduced in v9. You will need to load a package: `Needs["PlotLegends`"]` and use `PlotLegend` instead of `PlotLegends`. Look at the documentation for `PlotLegend`. When asking questions you should specify your version. Few people are using a version released over 9 years ago.